# Creating a Mock DetactedCreteria Object

Tags: mocking, moq

I have a function in my service layer whose output needs to be mocked.
it takes in a **FinanceAccount** object and returns a List
the function uses the **FinanceAccount** object to create a **DetachtedCreteria**.
and fetch a List.

How can I SetUp this function so that it returns separate Lists for 3 three different FinanceAccount objects.

I am using Moq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the design of the service layer being tested was wrong. each part of the servicer layer should have been created with unit tests  in mind.rather than refactoring tests after the code was written.